# How does discontinuities point of derivative affect differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am learning calculus. There is one thing that confuses me.

If a function has continuous partial derivatives, then it is differentiable. However, a function is differentiable, but the partial derivatives may or may not be continuous.

Considering the discontinuity of partial derivatives, discontinuity points are classified into three types, which are removable points, jump discontinuities, and essential discontinuity.

If there is a differentiable function, and its derivative function has removed discontinuous points, What is it like? How about if the derivative function has a jump discontinuous point?

For a differentiable function, how does the classification of discontinuities point, which the derivative(or dartial derivative)  has, affect the differentiable function?

Can you give some examples?

Comment: [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) states that derivatives can not have jump discontinuities.

Comment: How about this function: `f(x) = 0, when x<0` and `f(x) = x when 0=<x<=1` and `f(x) = 1 when x>1`, its derivatives: `f'(x) = 0 when x<0 or x>1` and `f'(x) = 1 when 0<x<1`

Comment: That function is not differentiable at $x=0$ and $x=1$. Darboux's theorem applies to functions $f: I \to \Bbb R$ which are differentiable everywhere on an interval $I$.